# Generation of different templates for different rectangles in python

Tags: python, qml, shapes

I have to detect the coordinates of rectangles in a given image and then import these data into a `.qml` file, I've been able to do so, but the problem is that my code generate a new template for each rectangle in my image, but I want one template for all the detected rectangles. I don't know if I should add another if condition or what exactly! I tried adding a for loop just before this line `output_file.write('  \n\n  Rectangle')` but it didn't work!

you'll find below an extract of my code:

```
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename # Open dialog box
from PIL import Image
from string import Template
def center_of_shape():
    # import the necessary packages
    from pyimagesearch.shapedetector import ShapeDetector
    import argparse
    import imutils
    import cv2
    import numpy as np
    import os
    import string
    outputname='cordinations.txt'
    myfile = open(outputname,'w')
    shapes=["rectangle", "circle", "triangle", "square"]
    # load the image and resize it to a smaller factor so that
    filename = askopenfilename(filetypes=[("image","*.png")])
    image=cv2.imread(filename,1)
    width, height,channels = image.shape
    resized = imutils.resize(image, width=300)
    ratio = image.shape[0] / float(resized.shape[0])
    # convert the resized image to grayscale, blur it slightly and threshold it
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(resized, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)
    thresh = cv2.threshold(blurred, 60, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
    edged = cv2.Canny(gray, 75, 200)
    # find contours in the thresholded image and initialize the
    cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(),cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnts = cnts[0] if imutils.is_cv2() else cnts[1]
    sd = ShapeDetector()

    print("Item:")
    print("{")
    #loop over the contours
    for c in cnts:
       # compute the center of the contour, then detect the name of the
       # shape using only the contour
       M = cv2.moments(c)
       cX = int((M["m10"] / M["m00"]) * ratio)
       cY = int((M["m01"] / M["m00"]) * ratio)
       shape = sd.detect(c)
       c = c.astype("float")
       c *= ratio
       c = c.astype("int")        
       # Prints caracteristics of a rectangle
       if shape == "rectangle":
           x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
           cv2.rectangle(image,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),0)
           myfile.write('The cordinations of the rectangle are :\n')
           myfile.write('x : '+str(x)+'\n')
           myfile.write('y : '+str(y)+'\n')
           myfile.write('width : '+str(w)+'\n')
           myfile.write('height : '+str(h)+'\n')
           #Open template file and pass string to 'data'.
           with open('cordinations.txt', 'r') as my_template:
               data = my_template.read()
               # Print template for visual cue.
               print('Template loaded:')
               print(data)
               # Pass 'data' to string.Template object data_template.
               data_template = string.Template(data)             
               cordinates=[]
               cordinates.append(dict(abscisse=x,ordonee=y,width=w,height=h))
               t=Template("""
    x: $abscisse
    y: $ordonee
    w: $width
    h: $height
    """)
               print "    Rectangle:"
               print("      {")
           for data in cordinates:
              print (t.substitute(data))
              print("      }")
         # Open QML output file and fill its contents by string substitution
           with open("main.qml", 'a') as output_file:
               # Run string.Template substitution on data_template
               # using data from 'values' as source and write to 'output_file'.
               output_file.write('import QtQuick 2.2')
               output_file.write('\nItem')
               output_file.write("  \n{")
               output_file.write("   id:\n")
               output_file.write('   height: '+str(height)+'\n')
               output_file.write('   width: '+str(width)+'\n')
               output_file.write('  \n\n  Rectangle')
               output_file.write("   \n   {")
               output_file.write('    \n            id:')
               output_file.write(t.substitute(data))
               output_file.write("}")
               output_file.write("\n}")
               output_file.close()
          #Print QML generated code for visual cue.
           with open('main.qml', 'r') as my_qml:
               qml_code = my_qml.read()
               print('QML code generated:')
               print(qml_code)

    # show the output image
    cv2.imshow("Shapes", image)
    cv2.waitKey(0)

from Tkinter import *
rw=Tk()
rw.title("My application menu")

#define  labels 
l1=Label(rw, text="The menu")
l1.grid(row=0,column=2)
l1=Label(rw, text="  ")
l1.grid(row=1,column=2)
l1=Label(rw, text="Apply shape detection")
l1.grid(row=4,column=0)
btn2=Button(rw,text="Shape detection", width =14)
btn2.grid(row=4, column=3)
btn2.config(command=center_of_shape)

rw.mainloop()
```

Thank you for your time and effort.

Comment: I think the simplest thing in your case is to create a CSV that stores the information of the rectangles and when you launch the application of PyQt read that information and dynamically create the rectangles through QML so you avoid many problems.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Why? Because I run your code to see how it works.

Comment: I've edited my code, to give you an example of my application.
Thank you